# Fatal error: Call to undefined function new_mysqli() in C:\wamp\www\work\conn.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a login page. The connection to mysqli keeps showing me this message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function new_mysqli() in
>   C:\wamp\www\work\conn.php on line 8

**conn.php**:

```
<?php

    $dbhost = "loaclhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "users";

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

?>
```

Comment: I havent seen a function `new_mysqli()` where did you get that code?Can you post your code inside conn.php?

Comment: Code please? nothing to check

Comment: In your code no where `new_mysqli()` is there. Please paste your original and full code

Comment: <?php
   //login script
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){ $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM 'user' WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"); header("Location: index.php");
    exit();

Comment: `$dbhost = "loaclhost";` I think its `$dbhost="localhost";`

Comment: @jameshwartlopez is right, change that one, silly mistake

Comment: if this is really the code throwing the error, mysqli might not be installed on your system. Maybe try installation of a current wampp. (please be aware that some code might (iE file ops) work on Windows but not on Linux Webservers as the latter are case sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

change `$dbhost = "loaclhost";` to `$dbhost = "localhost";`