# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\work\p_login_admin.php on line 14

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

session_start();

include "conn.php";

$username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";

$hasil = $conn->query($query);

$hitung = $hasil->num_rows;

if($hitung){

    $cetak = $hasil->fetch_assoc();
    extract($cetak);

    $_SESSION['id_users'] = $id_users;
    echo '<script>window.alert("Welcome you had been logged in");windows.location=("../work/admin.php");</script>';
}
else{
    echo '<script>window.alert("Sorry,username or password is wrong");windows.location("../work/login.php");</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: your query failed, you failed to check for failure, and are now trying to use the boolean `false` that was returned to TELL YOU about the failure as if it was an object. In other words, never **EVER** assume success with db operations (or using any external resource). always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: If your query returns nothing, $conn->query($query) will return false.

Comment: thx but can u help me pls

Comment: how do i fix this KayVan

Comment: what does `conn.php` look like?

Comment: my conn.php                                                                                                                                      <?php

    $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "";
 $dbname = "web";
 
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of "I need to learn how to problem solve"

Comment: tha guys for your help if fix it thx thx everybody

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 12> $hasil = $conn->query($query);
> 13> 
> 14> $hitung = $hasil->num_rows;
> ```

`$hasil` is not an object. `$hasil` is the contents of `->query` method part of the `$conn` object.

Your error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\work\p_login_admin.php on line 14

So this should tell you that on line 14, the source item is not an object, yet you are treating it as an object.

Solutions:

1) You almost certainly don't want the contents of the `$hasil` variable but the original contents of the `$conn` Object. Without knowing what your `$conn` object contains or what the class contains or even how your output is expected to be the choices for you depend on these details you have yet to share with us.

However, the details of a solution depend on knowing what exact elements and structures we're working with.

*(Also please ensure that your questions contain all the details required that a solution can be presented.)*

---

**EDIT:**

Viewing [Fatal error: Call to undefined function new_mysqli() in C:\wamp\www\work\conn.php on line 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007100/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-new-mysqli-in-c-wamp-www-work-conn-ph) shows me the start of your `conn.php` script. So

```
$hitung = $conn->num_rows;
```

This should give you the correct result direct from the MySQLi object (started within the conn.php file).

Also be aware that the query data returned to `$hasil`
will NOT be ready to use in PHP because you will still need to run a **MySQLi Fetch** method on the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in this line `$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";`

It wasn't admin it should be users.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include "conn.php";

    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";

    $hasil = $conn->query($query);

    $hitung = $hasil->num_rows;

    if($hitung){

        $cetak = $hasil->fetch_assoc();
        extract($cetak);

        $_SESSION['id_users'] = $id_users;
        echo '<script>window.alert("Welcome you had been logged in");windows.location=("work/admin.php");</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<script>window.alert("Sorry,username or password is wrong");windows.location("work/login.php");</script>';
    }
?>
```